# Mongoose - pre validate don't work with updateOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following code that update some data:

```
const update = {};

if (dateStart) {
  update.dateStart = dateStart;
}

if (dateEnd) {
  update.dateEnd = dateEnd;
}

await StatsBoard.updateOne(
  {
    id,
    type,
    user: req.user.id
  },
  update,
  { runValidators: true }
);
```

I need to do some custom validations, so I added a pre validate hook:

```
StatsBoardSchema.pre('validate', function (next) {
  console.log('VALIDATE');
  next();
});
```

But I never enter the pre validate hook even if I correctly set `{ runValidators: true }` in the `updateOne`. Is there a solution to this?

Comment: Did you find anything for this ?